# how to block developers from debug on production

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

lately my team deployed our app to production, and now we have 3 environments: dev, tests, and production. Now, I have a config file with a parameter of the URL of the DB (of course there are 3 DB's, one for each environment).

Using maven, I have 3 profiles in the pom file, one for each environment, so in dev, maven automatically creates a config file for dev. But the problem is that if a developer, accidentally, saves in the config file the URL of the production DB, instead of the dev DB, it will cause a lot of problems in the production.

How can I block the developers from access the production DB while developing?

NOTE:

1) I want that the developers will have access to the production DB in general, just not while developing.

2) We are using java, intellij, and maven, so I thought there might be a solution with maven, or a plugin for intellij...

Thank you

Comment: You never mentioned how the credentials to the DBs were configured/controlled.  I sure hope people can't access the production DB just as long as they get hold of the url, or all three DBs use the same user id/password?

Comment: Profiles are not meant to be used to distinguish environment like dev and prod. The artifact should be built once, then tested and then to production. You should not rebuild artifacts for different stages/environments.

Comment: Furthermore, I do not understand why a developer should have access to production databases. This could cause all kinds of security issues, and may furthermore be an issue with data protection.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty good use case for a config server.

It would allow you to control access to the configs themselves, rather than mix that into your projects. Production config can be blocked from dev access for example. And dev configs blocked from production users.

Spring Cloud Config is a good candidate if it can be included in your tech stack.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/

Comment: Git repository of the config server code base is still accessible to developers, it is project long process updating the properties. How does creating config server going to help?

Comment: I understood the issue to be "accidental" use of production when developing. Config server can at least prevent a production config being used by accident. Pull requests of config file updates in GIT can control a developer accidentally adding production DB details to a dev config.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical use case for containerization. If you can deploy your app in a docker environment that would be great, you can set config as environment variables. The devops code would build docker image for dev, qa and prod with separate environment variables.

Please see https://12factor.net/config

If you are not close to containerization then you can do something similar -

1) Don't include the config in the jar file during build process.

2) During deploy process place a properties file for a given environment and the jar. You can source control your properties file as part of deployment devops code.

During development process the developers can have a copy of the dev properties file which they don't need to commit to source control. If they commit it by mistake then no issue because build process ignores it and deployment would add the property file as per the environment.